# How can I create a new table in a Hibernate Java web service without introducing a SQL injection flaw?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a Java web service that uses Hibernate. One of its methods is designed to create a new table in SQL Server, and that table isn't mapped to an object. The current design accepts the database name, schema name, table name, and the field definitions as arguments, and executes creates a query string from them, and then executes it. It works fine, but it is a SQL injection flaw.

Is there a way to create a table without introducing this flaw, for instance using a parameterized query, or using some feature in Hibernate I don't know about?

The flaw happens at the call to createSQLQuery:

```
String sSql = "CREATE TABLE [" + sDatabaseName + "].[" + sSchema + "].[" + sTableName + "] (" + sSqlFields + ")";
Session session = getSession(); 
Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sSql);
q.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. You can parameterise a query like:

```
String sSql = "CREATE TABLE [ ? ].[ ? ].[ ? ] (?)";
Query q = session.createQuery(sSql);
q.setString(0, sDatabaseName)
 .setString(1, sSchema)
 .setString(2, sTableName)
 .setString(3, sSqlFields )
 .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I think that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem. FYI you can upvote or accept answers if they helped you.

Comment: I don't have the score yet to upvote, but I did accept the answer. Thanks again.